# How do I pass additional parameters into an event

Tags: javascript

I have an array of clickable links "btns"

```
for ( var i=0; i<btns.length; i++ ) {      
        btns[i].addEventListener('click', eventData, false);
```

eventData function is here:

```
function eventData(e) {
  dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'home_cta',
      'iteration': i, // HERE. I WANT TO ADD WHICH ELEMENT INDEX WITHIN THE FOR LOOP HERE
      'gtm.element': e.target,
      'gtm.elementClasses': e.target.className || '',
      'gtm.elementId': e.target.id || '',
      'gtm.elementTarget': e.target.target || '',
      'gtm.elementUrl': e.target.href || e.target.action || '',
      'gtm.originalEvent': e
    });
```

I have two questions:

1. How do I pass anything into eventData on each iteration? For example, if `var somevar = "bla"`, how would I pass that to eventData within my for loop?
2. I would like to pass the iteration number into eventData. I have highlighted this in the `'iteration'` property. So I'd like to end up with a number between 1 and 6 for each iteration (Because variable "btns" has length 6). How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would involve an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression):

```
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    (function(somevar, i) {
        btns[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            eventData(e, somevar, i);
        }, false);
    })(somevar, i);
}
```

`addEventListener` passes one argument and one argument only to its callback,
so you have to "manually" call your `eventData` function.

(Note that without the `(function() { ... })()`, each of the event listeners
would have `btns.length` passed to them as the value for `i`.)

To explain the IIFE a bit more, here's what you're basically doing:

```
var f = function(somevar, i) {
    // ...
};
f(somevar, i);
```

That is, you're creating a function and immediately invoking it (hence the
name). Again, this is done so that the value of `i` (and `somevar` if it
changes) are kept the same for the appropriate iteration.

Comment: Don't you also have to pass `somevar` and `i` into the IIFE: `(function(somevar, i) {`, or is that not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to "fixate" the first parameter of the bound function to the current index.

```
for (var i=0; i<btns.length; i++ ) {
    btns[i].addEventListener('click',
               // <this> in the function will be the clicked button (as usual)
               // but the first passed parameter would be the current iteration step <i>
               eventData.bind(btns[i], i),
               false);
}


function eventData(iteration, e) {
    //...
    'iteration': iteration,
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rhdLLjm/)